Cannot find 'Firebase' in scope
I'm relatively new to SwiftUI and have been following along with a tutorial to aid me in creating an app that has form validation and user login features, however I keep getting an error message that says

Cannot find 'Firebase' in scope

I have added the packages correctly but can't figure out what's going wrong. The errors throw in the createUser and fetchUser function calls.
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

protocol AuthenticationFormProtocol {
    var formIsValid: Bool { get }
}

@MainActor
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        Task {
            await fetchUser()
        }
    }
    
    func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String) async throws {
        do {
            let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
            await fetchUser()
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to login with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func createUser(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String) async throws {
        do {
            let result = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
            let user = User(id: result.user.uid, fullname: fullname, email: email)
            let encodedUser = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(user)
            try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.id).setData(encodedUser)
            await fetchUser()
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to create user with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.userSession = nil
            self.currentUser = nil
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to sign out with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func deleteAccount() {
        
    }

    func fetchUser() async {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        guard let snapshot = try? await

Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument() else { return }
        self.currentUser = try? snapshot.data(as: User.self)
        
        print("DEBUG: Current user is \(self.currentUser)")
    }
}

I've searched online but can't find anything that helps my case.

Are you missing import FirebaseAuth?

Sadly that doesnt fix it :(

Figured out the issue for anyone who stumbles across it. Refer to : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVhwL7MMLrc

Good to hear you got it working, Mikey!
